# Do I need any server adjustments in order to use fully HTML5 History API?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML5 History API (on Chrome), at the following link:

http://jsbin.com/zuqijofole/1

You can see a simple application which shows/hides div (Views).

Script works fine using browser backward and forward buttons but if I type directly in the browser the following address (in order to see View 2)
http://jsbin.com/zuqijofole/2

the document is not found. I need instead the second View to be shown.

I would like to know:

- Should I implement on server side some logic which map URL? Which
  coul be a solution using latest PHP?
- Or am I missing some implementation in my JS?

Notes: solution should work in a SPA application, so all data is rendered by JS app.

---

```
window.app = {
            data: {
                views: [
                        { id: 0, isActive: false },
                        { id: 1, isActive: false },
                        { id: 2, isActive: false },
                ]
            },
        start: function () {
            this.listeners();
            // default entry
            var activeView = this.wm.activeView;
            history.replaceState({ activeView: activeView }, document.title, document.location.href);

            window.app.wm.hideViews();
            window.app.wm.showView();

        },
        listeners: function () {
            window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
                // fires when backing/forwarding in history
                console.log(event);
                console.log(window.history.state);
                this.wm.showHideBl(event.state);
            }.bind(this));

            var elm = document.getElementById('btn-prev');
            elm.addEventListener('click', function () {
                window.app.wm.snowPrevView();
            });

            elm = document.getElementById('btn-next');
            elm.addEventListener('click', function () {
                window.app.wm.snowNextView();
            });

        },
        wm: {
            activeView: 0, // default
            showView: function () {
                var elm = document.getElementById('view-' + this.activeView);
                elm.style.display = '';
            },
            showHideBl: function (data) {
                this.hideView();
                this.activeView = data.activeView;
                this.showView();
            },
            snowNextView: function () {
                // bl
                if (this.activeView < window.app.data.views.length - 1) {
                    this.hideView();
                    this.activeView++;
                    this.showView();
                    history.pushState({ activeView: this.activeView }, '', this.activeView);
                }
            },
            snowPrevView: function () {
                // bl
                if (this.activeView > 0) {
                    this.hideView();
                    this.activeView--;
                    this.showView();
                    history.pushState({ activeView: this.activeView }, '', this.activeView);
                }
            },
            hideView: function () {
                var elm = document.getElementById('view-' + this.activeView);
                elm.style.display = 'none';
            },
            hideViews: function () {
                window.app.data.views.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
                    var elm = document.getElementById('view-' + item.id);
                    elm.style.display = 'none';
                }.bind(this));
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: Yes you need to check the for URL variables and need to write the logic as per the variables present in the url.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy do you mean to add logic in the JS solution?

Comment: Yes few days back while using history api I had a similar kind of issue, So I checked the URL values on document .ready and the proceeded forward by making ajax calls depending upon the url variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for a completely seamless experience, you want that all URLs created by the History API to be mapped to actual URLs that the server can use.

For example, if you have a table that you can sort client side, you can use the history API to save the sorting state into the URL. The server should be able to read that URL and serve a table already sorted when the page is refreshed.

The best way to make sure everything works as intended is to disable JavaScript and make sure you can still navigate and use the site correctly (even though the page refreshes all the time).